# If Luke 1:17 was quoting the LXX version of Malachi 4:6, Why was ἐπιστρέφω used for “to turn” instead of copying ἀποκαθίστημι?

Tags: luke, septuagint, malachi, historical-criticism, grammatical-historical

Should historians think Luke’s author used an available copy of LXX to reference Malachi 4:6, if the LXX-Malachi uses the Greek word “ἀποκαθίστημι” instead of “ἐπιστρέφω” in Luke 1:17?

[LXX Malachi 4:6] ὃς **ἀποκαταστήσει** καρδίαν πατρὸς πρὸς υἱὸν καὶ καρδίαν ἀνθρώπου πρὸς τὸν πλησίον αὐτοῦ μὴ ἔλθω καὶ πατάξω τὴν γῆν ἄρδην

[LXX Luke 1:17] καὶ αὐτὸς προελεύσεται ἐνώπιον αὐτοῦ ἐν πνεύματι καὶ δυνάμει Ἠλίου **ἐπιστρέψαι** καρδίας πατέρων ἐπὶ τέκνα καὶ ἀπειθεῖς ἐν φρονήσει δικαίων ἑτοιμάσαι κυρίῳ λαὸν κατεσκευασμένον

**Why did the Author of LXX-Luke not directly quote from his copy of LXX-Malachi, if Luke 1:17 was directly referencing Malachi 4:6?**

Answer (score 2):

The text of Luke 1:17 is:

> καὶ αὐτὸς προελεύσεται ἐνώπιον αὐτοῦ ἐν πνεύματι καὶ δυνάμει Ἡλεία,
> ἐπιστρέψαι καρδίας πατέρων ἐπὶ τέκνα καὶ ἀπειθεῖς ἐν φρονήσει δικαίων,
> ἑτοιμάσαι Κυρίῳ λαὸν κατεσκευασμένον. = And he will go on before the
> Lord in the spirit and power of Elijah, to **turn** the hearts of the
> fathers to their children and the disobedient to the wisdom of the
> righteous—to make ready a people prepared for the Lord.”

The text of Mal 4:4, 5 (LXX) is:

> καὶ ἰδοὺ ἐγὼ ἀποστελῶ ὑμῖν ᾿Ηλίαν τὸν Θεσβίτην, πρὶν ἢ ἐλθεῖν τὴν
> ἡμέραν Κυρίου τὴν μεγάλην καὶ ἐπιφανῆ, ὃς **ἀποκαταστήσει** καρδίαν
> πατρὸς πρὸς υἱὸν καὶ καρδίαν ἀνθρώπου πρὸς τὸν πλησίον αὐτοῦ, μὴ ἐλθὼν
> πατάξω τὴν γῆν ἄρδην = And, behold, I will send to you Elias the
> Thesbite, before the great and glorious day of the Lord comes; 5 who
> **shall turn** again the heart of the father to the son, and the heart of
> a man to his neighbour, lest I come and smite the earth grievously

Observe that the text of Luke 1:17 is only vaguely similar to the LXX and does not really follow it at all.  The Hebrew of Mal 4:5, 6 is

> Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet before the coming of the
> great and awesome Day of the LORD. And he **will turn** the hearts of the
> fathers to their children, and the hearts of the children to their
> fathers. Otherwise, I will come and strike the land with a curse.”

Neither is the text of Luke 1:17 all that similar to the Hebrew.  Indeed, Luke appears to to paraphrase both.